# Hard reset and restore of iPad from a 2nd desktop computer?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id, restore

I'm maintaining a series of iPads used in kiosk context for a client. Occasionally the  iPads become 'locked' and require a hard reset and restore from my Mac which was used for the original deploy.
My question is, can I somehow allow the unlocking and restore on a 2nd desktop (the client's) Mac? Isn't the iPad 'tied' to just one Mac, the one used for the original deploy? Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

If you are resetting these things and then restoring then from a saved local backup that second part is tied to your Mac.

You can reset an iPad to its "factory fresh" state from any Mac/PC, but you might not be able to reset an iPad to your desired "factory fresh eco_bach kiosk" state from any but yours.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely mistaken ;) it can be done by any computer, Mac or PC! As long as you have the IPSW file you can restore it from iTunes on any platform. It's only 'tied' when you sync your iPhone with iTunes library.